# Android studio library model R.string or R.drawable invalid

Tags: android, android-studio

An android project ‘app’ use a lib model ‘gp_model’,the gp_model's R.string or R.drawable is invalid.
Clean/rebuild project can't word.
The Messages is "Package R does not exist".
Android studio(1.5) Build Tools version 22.0.1.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when some of your `.xml` files is corrupt, and it's generally a pain to fix.

The best way to fix it is checking your `.xml` files and trying to undo your changes, until the change that caused your `R` file to disappear gets undone. I've faced this problem a couple times and this is how I fixed it. I sincerely don't know why Android Studio seems to crash at some points when you change some of your `.xml` files, even if your changes seem to be logical.

If you can't undo the changes, then try to **Invalidate Cache and Restart** in **File** options.
If it doesn't work either, you can also try to **Sync Project With Grade Files**.

Comment: The xml and code is copy here.I replaced the Build Tools,It works.but i don't know why.But it works! Thanks!